# Show detail Segue is not working when I use with manual

Tags: ios, uitableview, segue, uisplitview

I'm using splitview controller in my app. I directly connect UITableViewCell to detailViewController with segue.I used show detail. It's working fine.

However, it's not working, when I call manually segue instead of connect in storyboard. I'm using manual segue and connect between viewcontrollers.

It doesn't show up in detailview (right side). It only replace at the current left side view.

Why it's not showing and how can I fix ?

My code is like

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "browseToDetail", sender: myobject)
tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
```

Edit:

Try to create new project and copy/paste the code. It's working :( No idea why not working in old project.

Comment: it will not working if your controller not connected to using segue identifier browseToDetail .

Comment: @KKRocks connect and it's working. But show in left side instead of right side. If I am not using manual trigger and direct connect to the cell action segue , it's working fine

Comment: did you segue identifier in stroryboard ?